# "Write after end" error comes up after data insertion

Tags: node.js, reactjs, postgresql, express

I am using express to handle the connection to my postgres database. I am using React JS for my front end. The data writes to the database fine, but after each insertion I have to restart the server because the "Write after end" error comes up. Here's the portion of my server.js file that I believe is causing the problem:

```js
    pool.connect((err, db, done) => {
     if(err) {
         return response.status(400).send(err);
     } else {
         db.query('INSERT INTO news (headline, date, content, images, id, snippet, author) VALUES($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7)',[...values], (err, table) => {
             done();
             if (err) {
                 return response.status(400).send(err);
             } else {
                 console.log('DATA INSERTED');
                 db.end();
             }
         })
     }
 })
```

Please let me know your thoughts on how to handle this issue.

Answer (score 0):

So, the problems seems to have come from the "db.end()" portion. Once I removed that and added a respsonse.status(201) the error went away. Here's my updated code:

```js
    pool.connect((err, db, done) => {
     if(err) {
         return response.status(400).send(err);
     } else {
         db.query('INSERT INTO news (headline, date, content, images, id, snippet, author) VALUES($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7)',[...values], (err, table) => {
             done();
             if (err) {
                 return response.status(400).send(err);
             } else {
                 return response.status(201).send(`Data Inserted`);
             }
         })
     }
 })
```